# Show only text in inner XML tags using CSS

Tags: css, xml

If I have the below `XML` code:

```
<member name="componentName">
    Don't show this text.
    <summary>Do show this text.</summary>
</member>
```

What can I do in terms of `CSS` to show the inner text? I have tried setting the `member` `display` to `none` and the `summary` display to `block` as well as setting the `member` font size to zero, but with no luck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```css
member {
  color: transparent; 
  font-size:0;
  line-height:0;
}
member summary {
  color:#000;
  font-size:18px;
}
```

```html
<member name="componentName">
    Don't show this text.
    <summary>Do show this text.</summary>
</member>
```